# Slicing lists in python

Tags: python-2.7, slice

There is a hell lot of confusion on how exactly does slice operation work on lists.

- Why does [1,2,3,4][::-1] return its reverse?
- Why does [1,2,3,4][1:-4] return [] and [1,2,3,4][1:-4:-1] return [2] ?

The main problem occurs when using negative indices.

It will be good if someone could show me the exact definition of slice in the built-in module.

Edit: Why do [1,2,3][::-1] and [1,2,3][0:3:-1] have different return values

Comment: Check this out http://www.diveintopython3.net/native-datatypes.html#lists

Comment: @imvpn22 all that is pretty basic. My question is more confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

**Index** from 0 to size-1.

Negative index means going through the list backward :

```
       negative index   |   positive index
-5   -4   -3   -2   -1  |  0    1    2    3    4
     'A'  'B', 'C', 'D',|['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Index > 4 or < -5 throw IndexError.

**Slices** follow this pattern : List[from:to:step]

- step, defaults to one, indicates which indexes to keep in slice
  its sign gives the direction of slicing

  - positive, for left to right,
  - negative for right to left
- from index where to start the slicing, inclusive

  - defaults to 0 when step is positive,
  - defaults to -1 when step is negative
- to index where to end the slicing, exclusive

  - default to size-1 when step is positive,
  - (size-1) when step is negative

examples :

['A','B','C','D'][::-1] means from right to left, from -1 to -(size-1)  => ['D', 'C', 'B', 'A']

['A','B','C','D'][1:-4] means from second element to first element excluded with step of one => nothing

['A','B','C','D'][1:-4:-1] means from second element to first element excluded with step of minus one, only second element left => [2]

Of course, the best is always to try a slice on samples before using it.

Comment: Why is [1,2,3][::-1] and [1,2,3][0:3:-1] not same?

Comment: [::-1] means from end to start, step -1 which gives revered list. [0:3:-1] means from start to end step -1 which leads to empty.

Comment: This is an important answer. Other languages use [start:run length] and concentration can lapse.

Comment: @vaanchitkaul,  [1,2,3][::-1] and [1,2,3][-1:-4:-1] **are** the same.